# Modify existing Foreign Key to include Update Cascade

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 & SQL Azure database for my environment. I have defined primary keys and foreign keys and their constraint names too. I now want to change the primary key values but I cannot do it since the foreign keys not allowing me to do since they are not specified as `UPDATE CASCADE` when the PK-FK relationship / constraints were defined.

Is there any SQL statement by which in the existing constraints I can include the `UPDATE CASCADE` and henceforth change my primary key values?

Comment: What is the meaning of changing primary key?

Comment: I meant, changing the values of the column which is primary key

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can only define those attributes like `ON UPDATE CASCADE` when you create the constraint.

So you'll need to drop the constraint and re-create it with the proper attributes.

If you need to drop the primary key constraint, you'll have to

- drop all FK constraints referencing that PK
- then drop and re-create your PK constraint
- and in the end, re-create the dropped FK constraints

Comment: T-SQL Script would be much helpful